# Running a Spring Boot app from IntelliJ doesn't recognize src/main/resources/META-INF/orm.xml but it works when executing the jar

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm working on a project that contains an `orm.xml` in `src/main/resources/META-INF`.  When executing the jar, everything works fine, the `orm.xml` is found and the mappings are applied.  If I run the app from within IntelliJ using a Spring Boot run configuration, the `orm.xml` is not found, yet I can see it in the `target/classes/META-INF` directory.  I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing.  I have another project with the same setup that runs fine in IntelliJ.  Neither project has the JPA facet applied, so I don't think that's the issue.

If I define a bean like the following, then it works fine in IntelliJ, but I would rather have Spring Boot auto configure my entity manager.

```
@Inject
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setMappingResources("META-INF/orm.xml");
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.example");
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.DB2);
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return emf;
}
```

I'm runnig Intellij 2016.3 EAP build 163.4830.24.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does a [search in the issue tracker help](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues?q=is%3Aissue+orm.xml+is%3Aopen)? check both opened and closed issue.

Comment: Thanks Stephane.  I had seen a few other issues on the issue tracker that didn't quite match what I was looking for.  This one is spot on.  I've already implemented the work around.  Never occurred to me that it was due to upgrading SB to 1.4.1 Merci ;)